# How to multiply all elements in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, multiplication

I found it difficult to multiply all my elements of an array. I am writing two arrays of elements, and after that I am merging those two arrays to one array of negative numbers. Later, I want to multiply all elements of that merged array. This is my try:

```
    int mul = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < negativecount; ++i)
    {
        mul = mul * merge[i];
    }
    cout << mul << endl;
}
```

And I am getting random numbers as the answer. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: You should get `0` as result when you run that code....

Comment: Start by `mul=1`.....but if you get random number as ans then that may be due to `i` reaching value to make Array out of bounds. ..

Comment: You can also use `int mul = std::accumulate(merge, merge + negativecount, 1, multiplies<int>());`

Comment: @Wimmel sometime I get 0

Comment: This code will not produce "random numbers as answer". This code will always produce zero in `mul`. Please, don't "invent" imaginary problems and don't post fake code. Post real code and provide accurate description of the issue you are having.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The initial value of `mul` must be 1.

Answer (score 0):

As @Neil Kirk suggested you can use [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
int mul = std::accumulate(merge, merge + negativecount, 1, std::multiplies<int>());
```

And with C++17 and later you could use [`std::reduce`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce):

```
int mul = std::reduce(merge, merge + negativecount, 1, std::multiplies<int>());
```

Which behaves like `std::accumulate`. However, with `std::reduce` you can also specify an execution policy which may float your boat:

```
int mul = std::reduce(std::execution::par, merge, merge + negativecount, 1, std::multiplies<int>());
```

Answer (score -1):

Not only does your initial multiplication value have to be 1 like wrangler said. Also the value of your merge-array is important to know what answer you get.

Take a good look at this line:

```
mul = mul * merge[i];
```

What exactly do you try to accomplish here? Because you're not multiplying the numbers in the array, but only your multiplication factor? Because your 'mul' value in the end depends on both your starting value, your number of iterations and your merge[i] values, it can look random. The following code will provide you with a mul value of 2:

```
int mul = 2;
int negativecount = 10;

int *merge = (int*)malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < negativecount; ++i)
{
    merge[i] = 1;
    mul = mul * merge[i];
}
cout << mul << endl;
```

But I guess what you would want is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < negativecount; i++)
{
    merge[i] = merge[i] * mul;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Well, when the OP says that they want to "multiply all elements in the array" they can conceivably mean that they want to calculate the *product* of all elements in the array. The OP's code seems to suggest that latter intent.

Comment: Ah, didn't look at it that way :)